# Can running unity of a system with nvidia graphics card speed up the simulation?

Tags: unity, gpu, simulations

I have a nvidia GTX 1080 graphics card in my computer, I don't know if unity by default makes use of GPU. Does having a GPU helps to speed up unity simulations.

Comment: I assume you are asking if the Unity *physics* engine uses GPU acceleration? Because it is pretty obvious that the *rendering* will be faster on a better graphcis card.

Comment: yeah if it uses GPU by default, if not then to make it use GPU?